# Word for "smaller version of"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a descriptive words to indicate  *"smaller than the standard version"*.

Example:
I have a html form with some inputs. The inputs come in sizes (eg *small*, *normal*, *large*). Those sizes have a specific width.
Now, I have a version with a small button (in this case an X to delete). That button has a small width. I want the previous mentioned inputs to be a bit smaller, but "smaller" is confusing as it can also mean 'a smaller input' which can be confused with the input[size=small].

```
[--------------------] <- large
[-----------------][x] <- large + ??

[---------------] <- normal
[------------][x] <- normal + ??

[-------] <- small
[----][x] <- small + ??
```

Two words could be used in it really has to, but you work like this:
`<input class="normal someWord" />`

Comment: It is better if you stick with describing it in more than one word, else it might get confusing for whoever reads it.

Comment: Two words could be used in it really has to, but you work like this: `<input class="normal someWord"  />`, the reader should know approx. what is going on.

Comment: If it relates to the width then 'narrow' and 'wide' are the relevant adjectives. I also think 'standard' is better than 'normal' (as in 'standard width').

Comment: Also 'broad' and 'slim'

Comment: Just follow what's already been done: https://archive-2_0_3.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/spacing

Comment: Oh, I really love the Slim! Could you turn that into an answer @Stefan?

Comment: just x ? I think lux's answer is more appropriate

Comment: Or an edit, or a view, or a ??. In this case, the X is an example

Comment: **brev** would be short and not likely to conflict with other terms.

Comment: I want to add narrow as a answer, but I cant because I dont have enough rep. I've waited for @Stefan, but he doesnt respond. This way I cant close

Answer (score 1):

I suppose **mini** would suit this case. Also **compact**.

Although mini doesn't exactly mean *smaller than the standard version*, it comes close. I would prefer mini over compact, as mini is pretty has pretty common colloquial usage Ex: Ipod mini, Memory card sizes etc.

Answer (score 1):

From the context of your question it looks like the "smaller" versions are the same as the "standard" versions with a little bit cut off. In that case maybe something like `<input class="normal truncated" />`,  `<input class="normal clipped" />` or  `<input class="normal trimmed" />` might suit your needs? The words I have suggested have the following definitions

[truncate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truncate)

> to shorten by or as if by cutting off

[clip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clip)

> to cut off the distal or outer part of

[trim](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trim)

> to remove by or as if by cutting

Comment: Hi, these are not exactly what I'm looking for, but they're quite close! Trancated is a term I cant use (means something else), but the others are close, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surely the word for “smaller version of” is **diminutive**?
But that's not important right now, and don't call me Shirley!

Seriously, I'd try the good old-fashioned NIST prefixes:

```
micro-, nano-, pico-, femto-, atto-, etc.
```

See: https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html

That way you have an established order, plus you get the bonus of teaching your users something with broad applicability!

Comment: Hi 'Shirley', I do like this was of thinking but in my case that would get weird (unless I misunderstand): `class="large femto"` will still not really explain that it's a bit smaller. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

My Bad.  In my previous response (now deleted), I misunderstood your intent and I gave you a fourth size: “Extra Small", which is not what you are looking for.

Now that I understand that your intention is to create a smaller version of each of the three sizes, I suggest that:

### 1. You may want to consider changing the name of the middle size from “normal” to “medium” (unless changing it is beyond your control).

### 2. An appropriate word for downsizing each of the three sizes might be “petite”.

[--------------------] <- large

[-----------------][x] <- large + petite

[---------------] <- medium

[------------][x] <- medium + petite

[-------] <- small

[----][x] <- small + petite

### 3. Another word for downsizing each of the three sizes might be “minus” (or "narrow").

[--------------------] <- large

[-----------------][x] <- large + minus

[---------------] <- medium

[------------][x] <- medium + minus

[-------] <- small

[----][x] <- small + minus

### 4. As an alternative to downsizing, you might consider up-sizing – adding a word like, “plus” to the larger version (or "wide").

[-----------------][x] <- large + plus

[--------------------] <- large

[-------------[x] <- medium + plus

[---------------] <- medium

[----[x] <- small + plus

[------] <- small